# Is there a way to take input using excel/csv files in Cloudsim Package? I am testing a load balancing Vm allocation policy

Tags: java, virtual-machine, file-management, cloudsim

Is there a way to take input from excel sheet/csv file and print output of the console in a text file in Cloudsim package using eclipse.
I am testing a new load balancing vm allocation policy and for the same I need to test using atleast 10,000 vm and 50,000 cloudlets having heterogeneous parameters ( wrt size, MIPS, bw etc).
I tried using for loop but my results using homogeneous parameters are not desirable.
Its not possible to manually create so many objects as it gives "The code of method main(String[]) is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit" error.

Comment: The error message sounds like you have an insanely bloated `main` method. Have you tried breaking that up in multiple methods? You may also want to look into a Java or object oriented programming tutorial.

Comment: I know, but what I want is to use a file for inputing VMs in cloudsim package.